# Play framework: URLs in ajax queries

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In HTML, I would do routes.ControllerName.Method to present a link to user that will automatically change when I rename the URLs. How should I do it in links in javascript ajax query URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up [Javascript Reverse Routing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting) in the docs.

Basically, a Play reverse router will generate equivalent JS functions (namespaced per controller) to obtain an URL given the appropriate parameters for each particular action. You then define a separate route to load that JS whenever you need access to those URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find that typing the URL in the JavaScript file makes it the much more readable.

You didn't supply any code so I've included some of my own.

In my one of my Angular factories, I would have something like this

```
var mainroute = "/api/security";
        var submitLogin = function (login) {
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: mainroute + "/login",
                data: login
            });
        };
```

Then in my route file, I would only need to add the route.

```
# API
POST        /api/security/login                     controllers.Security.Login()
```

Using the `mainroute` variable I can quickly change the parent URL to all the methods.

Comment: My point was that if I change the /api/security/login route, then I need to remember to change the javascript as well, not something i am very keen on.. 
But thanks for your view.